# Angular Build - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, angular-cli

I have managed to build my angular app out as a dev build. I haven't done it as a production build yet as it gives me a few errors and i just need to test the dev build.

The dev build process goes fine, no errors or anything. I then use the files from the dist folder in a nginx docker container to host the files.

The problem is nothing is displayed but a white page and in the console i get an error saying 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined'. The full message below doesn't seem to point to anything i have written and i've spent several hours searching online but can't find anything on this problem.

[image]

I've tried a few different things such as running 'npx ivy-ngcc' which i read manually compiles some stuff. Is there anyway i can get more details on the error to see if it's something i have done?

**UPDATE**
So i have restored the line that i commented out in main.ts as mentioned in the comments below. I have also tried 'ng build --aot' as suggested which presents me with a series of errors that all seem to relate to devextreme components that are used. I find this strange as i started the project with the devextreme angular starter project from github.

i get messages such as:

1. 'dx-scroll-view is not a valid HTML element'
2. 'node_modules/devextreme-angular/ui/drawer.d.ts - error: appears in
       the NgModule.imports of SideNavOuterToolbarModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class'

Comment: Ok, so i think i might have solved it. I commented out "platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).catch(err => console.error(err));" from line 14 of my main.ts file. Now i just get a white screen but that could be docker related, not sure

Comment: You cannot comment out that line of code, that line of code launches your application. See [Angular - Bootstraping](https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping)

Comment: Have you tried clicking on "core.js:34425", perhaps it might show you a line of code that's written in your angular app that isn't working or perhaps it might be caused by a 3rd party lib

Comment: Just try your build version (ng build) to nginx not the production version. and try to get the error again.

Comment: i've posted an update above based on the suggestions you all have made

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by disabling ivy in the angular compilation options. As soon as i did that it worked building both dev and production versions and is now working perfectly within Nginx.

Thanks to everyone who offered help :)

Comment: this worked for me.. after disabling it showed me the error on my code to fix

Comment: is there a way to use Ivy and get rid of this error?

Comment: How did you dsiable the ivy?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60290309/error-ng6002-appears-in-the-ngmodule-imports-of-appmodule-but-could-not-be-res answer from @MarcinG helped me solving this issue. I had added a component in the import instead of declarations of app.module.ts

Comment: This is no longer an answer because Ivy is the only compiler left.  You'll need to dig in and figure out the actual root cause of your error.

Answer (score 16):

[image]

If you go in the devtools and click on Sources, "Don't pause on exceptions" and check "Pause on caught expecptions" and continue until you get the "id error" you will find what module the error is thrown. In my case was a third party library called 'ngx-card/ngx-card' and it's module was the cause of the error (CardModule). Hope this will help find at least the cause of the error

[image]

Comment: Was useful for me. Thanks!

Comment: I could solve my problem because of your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In `tsconfig.json` of your Angular project, put this to disable Ivy, the new Angular template engine

```
{
  ...
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, if it's not something that you've written, it tends to be an issue w/ your implementation - i.e. "Visiting a food vendor and ordering a food item they don't provide".

I know it's not a specific answer, but ensuring that you have appropriately configured things in your app.module would be a good first step.  Perhaps attempting to build w/ AOT will also give you some more verbose failures that stem from attempting to build out.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps another poor soul.

To anyone using devextreme, make sure you update your version to at least 19.2.5

https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-angular/issues/975#issuecomment-580172291

> Starting with version 19.2.5 we support the IVY compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by changing from

```
loadChildren: './app/page/account/account.module#AccountModule'
```

to

```
loadChildren: () =>
  import('./app/page/account/account.module').then(
    (m) => m.AccountModule
  )
```

in `app-router.module.ts`

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your error is very likely to be a module that you needed to load explicitly but didn't, or a circular reference in your own modules.  Rodrigo has a good answer but to be more specific, you need to find the `registerNgModuleType` function in Angular's `core.js` and set a *conditional breakpoint* on the first line.  The condition should be `!ngModuleType || !ngModuleType.ɵmod`.  (You can set a conditional breakpoint in most modern browsers by right-clicking the line number.)

Once you've paused execution just before the exception happens, you can look at the value of `ngModuleType` if it's not undefined, or walk up a frame or two in the scope and see what the value of `imports` was.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this issue occurred while using Storybook.

The reason it happened was because of the way I was precompiling the node modules. I was doing:

**Incorrect**

`ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --first-only`

**Correct**

`ngcc`

Using this approach fixed it