# Angular 9 and Ivy: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined at registerNgModuleType

Tags: angular, ivy, angular9

This runtime error appeared after migration to Angular9 with switch on Ivy.
Our application it very big so I couldn't create any smaller repo.
Error says: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined at registerNgModuleType`

I tried:
 1. `npx ngcc --properties main` as proposed here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31314
 2. `ng build` / `ng build --prod` - everything compiles without errors, so I assume every dependency is supported by Ivy

Application works just fine without Ivy and I have no idea how to track down that issue if compiler shows no errors.
Any strategy or advice will be helpfull

Comment: Show us the runtime error.  Ivy is very strict to templates.  (I had trouble with 100vH instead of  100vh)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular Build - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57874644/angular-build-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-id-of-undefined)

Comment: @Marc It's in the title. Updated description to make it more noticable

Comment: @ShijilNarayan Good found, I'll check it and answer then

Comment: This is a [known issue with Ivy](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37661) but that link is closed/locked so don't expect them to fix it for you. You have to watch the compiler's behavior with devtools to find out what module is causing the problem.  In my case, it was a circular dependency between my project's modules.

Comment: @DzmitryVasilevsky I have same issues but in routermodule . can you please explain how you solved that?

Comment: Sorry, don't remember how fixed it